# How to stop continuous scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have created a TV guide with previous/next buttons to show the next/previous amount of hours. I have it working using the below code but the problem I am having is that when I click next it moves the value which I have set it (100px) but does not stop at the end of the end of the day which I want it to but instead it continues to scroll for as long as you wish to click next.

Does anyone have any advice? When I click next and inspect element the div `style="left: -100px"` click again it changes to `"left: -200px"` etc.

Check out the issue in this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/kskevq9b/

Comment: Please add html code too even better create jsfiddle for this

Comment: check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/33aw8oyo/1/ For me it gets stopped in both directions. Can you edit this fiddle and reproduce your issue

Comment: Sorry - Fiddle updated showing the issue http://jsfiddle.net/kskevq9b/

Comment: Put an if statement that checks where the last one (`id=23`) is at in regards to the right side, and move no further than you want to.

Comment: Ok but how do it stop it from moving past that?